# How can I get the value of epsilon of batchnorm layers of a saved network model implemented with Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization

I loaded a Tensorflow model from a '.pb' file and for some reason wanted to get the value of epsilon of batch-norm layers in the model (The model was not developed by myself so I did not know the settings of it).

For Keras models, I can define a layer variable and get epsilon as an attribute:

```
layer = model.get_layer('batchnorm_1') 
print(layer.epsilon)
```

However, there is no such convenient interface for Tensorflow. I can print out the gamma and beta and even moving mean of the batch-norm layer because these are nodes existed in the network. But how can I get the value of epsilon? There is no corresponding node in the model.